# Getting Node.js 0.4.2 to build/install on FreeBSD 8.2 amd64

Tags: freebsd, node.js

I've tried getting this working a few different ways:

```
building from ports (/usr/ports/www/node)
git clone -> ./configure, ./make
git clone -> ./configure, ./gmake
```

But it always ends up breaking in the end.
When using 'make' I simply get one line of output:
    Error expanding embedded variable.

When using 'gmake' I get some building, and then:
    Waf: Leaving directory '/usr/home/{user}/node/build
    Build failed:  -> task failed (err #2):
    {task: libv8.a SConstruct -> libv8.a}

I did check for a FreeBSD package, but the most recent they have, on ftp2.freebsd.com, is 0.2.6

Does this just not work on 64 bit BSD?

**Update:**
I've been finding a few posts on the web of people having similar issues with FreeBSD 64 so I figured I'd also try it out on a 32 bit install (*on a 32 bit machine, not the 64 being used from my original question*)
Same issue with '**make**' and the exact same error using '**gmake**'

> Build failed:   -> task failed (err #2):
>   {task: libv8.a SConstruct -> libv8.a}

I'd love to get this working on my FreeBSD64, but I'm beginning to think that node just doesn't work anymore for FreeBSD :(

Comment: I guess this might even be more of a "Can you build V8 on FreeBSD amd64?"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got It!!

I first got this working on FreeBSD 32 and after it worked I was then able to get it working on 64.
The only difference between the two processes was for the 32 bit I simply built v8 using

> $ scons

and for 64 bit

> $ scons os=freebsd arch=x64

***Here are the steps I used to get a successful build/install of node on FreeBSD amd64:***

- Checked out clean copies of both v8 and node
- Within the v8 root

  > $ scons os=freebsd arch=x64
  >   ... *build output* ...
  >   $ cp libv8* /usr/local/lib
- Within the node root

  > $ ./configure \
  >       --prefix=/usr/local \
  >       --shared-v8 \
  >       --shared-v8-includes=/home/jr/v8-read-only/include \
  >       --shared-v8-libpath=/usr/local/lib \
  >       --shared-v8-libname=v8
  >   $ gmake
  >   ... *build output* ...
  >   $ gmake install
  >   $ node --version
  >   v0.5.0-pre

Comment: The only other thing is that this built v0.5 and the question was for 0.4.2 (which is what I checked out when I originally asked the question, but today github has v0.5. Not sure if that would have resolved any earlier issues)

Answer (score 0):

You do not really need to check out node separately. Here's what worked for me:

```
$ sudo portmaster devel/pkg-config devel/libexecinfo devel/cmake devel/scons lang/python27
$ git clone https://github.com/joyent/node.git
$ cd node/deps/v8
$ git checkout v0.4.6
$ scons os=freebsd arch=x64
(takes a while to compile v8)
$ sudo cp libv8* /usr/local/lib
$ cd ~/node
$ ./configure \     
  --prefix=/usr/local \
  --shared-v8 \
  --shared-v8-includes=/home/mikl/node/deps/v8/include \
  --shared-v8-libpath=/usr/local/lib \
  --shared-v8-libname=v8
$ gmake
$ sudo gmake install
```

Answer (score 0):

I could only get v0.5.1 to work. In addition i had some issues with installing ie. the hiredis module, since the v8 headers was missing.

Assuming the following packages are installed:

- devel/pkg-config
- devel/libexecinfo
- devel/cmake
- devel/gmake
- devel/scons
- lang/python27
- lang/v8

I got it working using the commands:

```
cd /root/
$ git clone https://github.com/joyent/node.git
$ git checkout v0.5.1
$ cd ~/node
$ ./configure \
  --prefix=/usr/local \
  --shared-v8 \
  --shared-v8-includes=/usr/local/include \
  --shared-v8-libpath=/usr/local/lib \
  --shared-v8-libname=v8
$ gmake
$ gmake install
$ cp /usr/local/include/v8* /usr/local/include/node/
```

Pretty much the same as above, not the gmake dependency and that I had to copy the headers into the node folder for the hiredis module to compile.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /usr/ports/www/node && make install clean
```

Worked fine for me. So it looks like they fixed the problems that port had.